# 写真を一定量読み込むとメモリ不足になってしまうのですが

Tags: android, android-volley

VolleyのImageLoaderを用いてネットからListViewへ写真をロードしています。
キャッシュはLruCacheとImageLoader#ImageCasheを組み合わせています。
ImageLoaderなどはシングルトンです。

確認はエミュレータのNexus5(API22)で行っています。
写真のサイズは縦120dpになるようにしていて、画面上に1枚と2枚目が少し見える程度です。
ListViewは複数あり、それぞれをreplaceして切り替えています。
8ページ目まではスクロールしなければ普通にページ遷移できるのですが、9ページ目でメモリ不足と言われます。
また、前のページでスクロールして3枚以上の写真を見ていると、きちんと見られるページ数が減っていきます。

キャッシュは`Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()/1024`の1/8をmaxSizeとしているはずなのですが、メモリ使用量を見るとページを開くたびにみるみる消費されていて指定したサイズを超えているように見えます。
原因は何が考えられるでしょうか？

キャッシュ用クラスは以下の通りです。

```java
public static class ImageLruCache implements ImageLoader.ImageCache {
    private LruCache<String, Bitmap> mMemoryCache;

    public ImageLruCache() {
        int maxMemory = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024);
        int cacheSize = maxMemory / 8;

        mMemoryCache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(cacheSize) {
            @Override
            protected int sizeOf(String key, Bitmap bitmap) {
                return bitmap.getByteCount() / 1024;
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
        System.out.println(mMemoryCache.toString());
        System.out.println("maxMemory:" + Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024);
        System.out.println("totalMemory:" + Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() / 1024);
        System.out.println("freeMemory:" + Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory() / 1024);
        System.out.println("useMemory:" + ((Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() / 1024) - (Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory() / 1024)));
        return mMemoryCache.get(url);
    }

    @Override
    public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
        mMemoryCache.put(url, bitmap);
    }
}
```

ログは以下の通りです。
(一部情報を伏せています。)

```
07-21 15:50:46.811    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ LruCache[maxSize=8192,hits=0,misses=0,hitRate=0%]
07-21 15:50:46.811    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ maxMemory:65536
07-21 15:50:46.812    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ totalMemory:5890
07-21 15:50:46.812    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ freeMemory:457
07-21 15:50:46.812    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ useMemory:5433
07-21 15:50:46.884    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ LruCache[maxSize=8192,hits=0,misses=1,hitRate=0%]
07-21 15:50:46.884    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ maxMemory:65536
07-21 15:50:46.884    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ totalMemory:11699
07-21 15:50:46.884    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ freeMemory:0
07-21 15:50:46.884    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ useMemory:11699
07-21 15:50:49.794    2178-2235/jp.co.sakaguchi W/chromium﹕ [WARNING:jni_string.cc(28)] ConvertJavaStringToUTF8 called with null string.
07-21 15:50:49.855    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ LruCache[maxSize=8192,hits=0,misses=2,hitRate=0%]
07-21 15:50:49.855    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ maxMemory:65536
07-21 15:50:49.855    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ totalMemory:16096
07-21 15:50:49.855    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ freeMemory:3456
07-21 15:50:49.855    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ useMemory:12641
07-21 15:50:49.931    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ LruCache[maxSize=8192,hits=0,misses=3,hitRate=0%]
07-21 15:50:49.932    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ maxMemory:65536
07-21 15:50:49.932    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ totalMemory:19161
07-21 15:50:49.932    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ freeMemory:0
07-21 15:50:49.932    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ useMemory:19161
07-21 15:50:51.413    2178-2237/jp.co.sakaguchi W/chromium﹕ [WARNING:jni_string.cc(28)] ConvertJavaStringToUTF8 called with null string.
07-21 15:50:51.474    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ LruCache[maxSize=8192,hits=0,misses=4,hitRate=0%]
07-21 15:50:51.474    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ maxMemory:65536
07-21 15:50:51.474    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ totalMemory:23461
07-21 15:50:51.474    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ freeMemory:3425
07-21 15:50:51.474    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ useMemory:20037
07-21 15:50:51.531    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ LruCache[maxSize=8192,hits=0,misses=5,hitRate=0%]
07-21 15:50:51.531    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ maxMemory:65536
07-21 15:50:51.531    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ totalMemory:26971
07-21 15:50:51.531    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ freeMemory:0
07-21 15:50:51.531    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ useMemory:26972
07-21 15:50:51.567    2178-2190/jp.co.sakaguchi W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 8.262ms
07-21 15:50:51.702    2178-2185/jp.co.sakaguchi W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 7.901ms
07-21 15:50:52.038    2178-2190/jp.co.sakaguchi I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 401(10KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 29MB/29MB, paused 8.106ms total 29.733ms
07-21 15:50:52.791    2178-2238/jp.co.sakaguchi W/chromium﹕ [WARNING:jni_string.cc(28)] ConvertJavaStringToUTF8 called with null string.
07-21 15:50:52.872    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ LruCache[maxSize=8192,hits=0,misses=6,hitRate=0%]
07-21 15:50:52.872    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ maxMemory:65536F
07-21 15:50:52.872    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ totalMemory:30026
07-21 15:50:52.872    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ freeMemory:3424
07-21 15:50:52.872    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ useMemory:26602
07-21 15:50:52.913    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ LruCache[maxSize=8192,hits=0,misses=7,hitRate=0%]
07-21 15:50:52.913    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ maxMemory:65536
07-21 15:50:52.913    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ totalMemory:33528
07-21 15:50:52.913    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ freeMemory:0
07-21 15:50:52.913    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ useMemory:33528
07-21 15:50:53.012    2178-2190/jp.co.sakaguchi I/art﹕ Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 1375(113KB) AllocSpace objects, 12(6MB) LOS objects, 13% free, 25MB/29MB, paused 30.173ms total 56.540ms
07-21 15:50:54.171    2178-2235/jp.co.sakaguchi W/chromium﹕ [WARNING:jni_string.cc(28)] ConvertJavaStringToUTF8 called with null string.
07-21 15:50:54.282    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ LruCache[maxSize=8192,hits=0,misses=8,hitRate=0%]
07-21 15:50:54.282    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ maxMemory:65536
07-21 15:50:54.282    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ totalMemory:36989
07-21 15:50:54.282    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ freeMemory:3424
07-21 15:50:54.282    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ useMemory:33565
07-21 15:50:54.322    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ LruCache[maxSize=8192,hits=0,misses=9,hitRate=0%]
07-21 15:50:54.322    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ maxMemory:65536
07-21 15:50:54.322    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ totalMemory:40491
07-21 15:50:54.322    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ freeMemory:0
07-21 15:50:54.322    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ useMemory:40492
07-21 15:50:55.554    2178-2236/jp.co.sakaguchi W/chromium﹕ [WARNING:jni_string.cc(28)] ConvertJavaStringToUTF8 called with null string.
07-21 15:50:55.609    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ LruCache[maxSize=8192,hits=0,misses=10,hitRate=0%]
07-21 15:50:55.609    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ maxMemory:65536
07-21 15:50:55.609    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ totalMemory:43947
07-21 15:50:55.609    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ freeMemory:3424
07-21 15:50:55.609    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ useMemory:40523
07-21 15:50:55.674    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ LruCache[maxSize=8192,hits=0,misses=11,hitRate=0%]
07-21 15:50:55.674    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ maxMemory:65536
07-21 15:50:55.674    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ totalMemory:46991
07-21 15:50:55.674    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ freeMemory:0
07-21 15:50:55.674    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ useMemory:46991
07-21 15:50:56.135    2178-2190/jp.co.sakaguchi I/art﹕ Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 156(7KB) AllocSpace objects, 3(4MB) LOS objects, 7% free, 46MB/50MB, paused 7.580ms total 22.873ms
07-21 15:50:57.087    2178-2237/jp.co.sakaguchi W/chromium﹕ [WARNING:jni_string.cc(28)] ConvertJavaStringToUTF8 called with null string.
07-21 15:50:57.123    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ LruCache[maxSize=8192,hits=0,misses=12,hitRate=0%]
07-21 15:50:57.123    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ maxMemory:65536
07-21 15:50:57.123    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ totalMemory:50904
07-21 15:50:57.123    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ freeMemory:3463
07-21 15:50:57.123    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ useMemory:47441
07-21 15:50:57.166    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ LruCache[maxSize=8192,hits=0,misses=13,hitRate=0%]
07-21 15:50:57.166    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ maxMemory:65536
07-21 15:50:57.166    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ totalMemory:53948
07-21 15:50:57.166    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ freeMemory:0
07-21 15:50:57.169    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ useMemory:53949
07-21 15:50:58.239    2178-2238/jp.co.sakaguchi W/chromium﹕ [WARNING:jni_string.cc(28)] ConvertJavaStringToUTF8 called with null string.
07-21 15:50:58.279    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ LruCache[maxSize=8192,hits=0,misses=14,hitRate=0%]
07-21 15:50:58.279    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ maxMemory:65536
07-21 15:50:58.280    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ totalMemory:57869
07-21 15:50:58.280    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ freeMemory:3424
07-21 15:50:58.280    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ useMemory:54445
07-21 15:50:58.330    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ LruCache[maxSize=8192,hits=0,misses=15,hitRate=0%]
07-21 15:50:58.331    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ maxMemory:65536
07-21 15:50:58.331    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ totalMemory:61381
07-21 15:50:58.331    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ freeMemory:0
07-21 15:50:58.331    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ useMemory:61381
07-21 15:50:58.689    2178-2190/jp.co.sakaguchi I/art﹕ Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 222(11KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 6% free, 58MB/62MB, paused 9.673ms total 29.542ms
07-21 15:50:58.724    2178-2236/jp.co.sakaguchi I/art﹕ Alloc sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 477(14KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 62MB/62MB, paused 1.237ms total 9.936ms
07-21 15:50:58.741    2178-2236/jp.co.sakaguchi I/art﹕ Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 246(12KB) AllocSpace objects, 3(4MB) LOS objects, 6% free, 58MB/62MB, paused 2.806ms total 12.968ms
07-21 15:50:59.643    2178-2235/jp.co.sakaguchi W/chromium﹕ [WARNING:jni_string.cc(28)] ConvertJavaStringToUTF8 called with null string.
07-21 15:50:59.721    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ LruCache[maxSize=8192,hits=0,misses=16,hitRate=0%]
07-21 15:50:59.721    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ maxMemory:65536
07-21 15:50:59.722    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ totalMemory:65222
07-21 15:50:59.722    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ freeMemory:3424
07-21 15:50:59.722    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ useMemory:61798
07-21 15:50:59.767    2178-2190/jp.co.sakaguchi I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 5577(228KB) AllocSpace objects, 6(225KB) LOS objects, 0% free, 63MB/63MB, paused 6.175ms total 16.146ms
07-21 15:50:59.768    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/art﹕ WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 14.318ms for cause Alloc
07-21 15:50:59.780    2178-2190/jp.co.sakaguchi W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 6.845ms
07-21 15:50:59.785    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/art﹕ Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 763(73KB) AllocSpace objects, 13(7MB) LOS objects, 6% free, 56MB/60MB, paused 2.870ms total 14.182ms
07-21 15:50:59.798    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ LruCache[maxSize=8192,hits=0,misses=17,hitRate=0%]
07-21 15:50:59.798    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ maxMemory:65536
07-21 15:50:59.798    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ totalMemory:62100
07-21 15:50:59.798    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ freeMemory:1208
07-21 15:50:59.798    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ useMemory:60892
07-21 15:51:00.229    2178-2237/jp.co.sakaguchi I/art﹕ Clamp target GC heap from 64MB to 64MB
07-21 15:51:00.229    2178-2237/jp.co.sakaguchi I/art﹕ Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 596(32KB) AllocSpace objects, 1(297KB) LOS objects, 5% free, 60MB/64MB, paused 1.129ms total 42.822ms
07-21 15:51:00.276    2178-2190/jp.co.sakaguchi I/art﹕ Clamp target GC heap from 67MB to 64MB
07-21 15:51:00.280    2178-2237/jp.co.sakaguchi I/art﹕ WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 12.467ms for cause Alloc
07-21 15:51:00.299    2178-2237/jp.co.sakaguchi I/art﹕ Alloc sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 0(0B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 63MB/64MB, paused 1.154ms total 5.816ms
07-21 15:51:00.316    2178-2237/jp.co.sakaguchi I/art﹕ Clamp target GC heap from 67MB to 64MB
07-21 15:51:00.316    2178-2237/jp.co.sakaguchi I/art﹕ Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 12(416B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 63MB/64MB, paused 1.152ms total 15.903ms
07-21 15:51:00.339    2178-2237/jp.co.sakaguchi I/art﹕ Clamp target GC heap from 67MB to 64MB
07-21 15:51:00.339    2178-2237/jp.co.sakaguchi I/art﹕ Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 8(12KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 63MB/64MB, paused 938us total 16.672ms
07-21 15:51:00.341    2178-2237/jp.co.sakaguchi I/art﹕ Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 1708KB allocation
07-21 15:51:00.355    2178-2237/jp.co.sakaguchi I/art﹕ Clamp target GC heap from 67MB to 64MB
07-21 15:51:00.355    2178-2237/jp.co.sakaguchi I/art﹕ Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 11(344B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 63MB/64MB, paused 1.218ms total 13.334ms
07-21 15:51:00.359    2178-2237/jp.co.sakaguchi E/art﹕ Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 1749612 byte allocation with 344768 free bytes and 336KB until OOM"
07-21 15:51:00.373    2178-2237/jp.co.sakaguchi I/art﹕ Alloc sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 5(368B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 63MB/64MB, paused 435us total 13.655ms
07-21 15:51:00.390    2178-2237/jp.co.sakaguchi I/art﹕ Clamp target GC heap from 67MB to 64MB
07-21 15:51:00.391    2178-2237/jp.co.sakaguchi I/art﹕ Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 10(336B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 63MB/64MB, paused 1.863ms total 10.959ms
07-21 15:51:00.409    2178-2237/jp.co.sakaguchi I/art﹕ Clamp target GC heap from 67MB to 64MB
07-21 15:51:00.409    2178-2237/jp.co.sakaguchi I/art﹕ Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 5(224B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 63MB/64MB, paused 1.622ms total 13.938ms
07-21 15:51:00.412    2178-2237/jp.co.sakaguchi I/art﹕ Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 1708KB allocation
07-21 15:51:00.428    2178-2237/jp.co.sakaguchi I/art﹕ Clamp target GC heap from 67MB to 64MB
07-21 15:51:00.428    2178-2237/jp.co.sakaguchi I/art﹕ Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3(96B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 63MB/64MB, paused 1.221ms total 13.563ms
07-21 15:51:00.430    2178-2237/jp.co.sakaguchi E/art﹕ Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 1749612 byte allocation with 344384 free bytes and 336KB until OOM"
07-21 15:51:00.431    2178-2237/jp.co.sakaguchi E/Volley﹕ [160] ImageRequest.parseNetworkResponse: Caught OOM for 304176 byte image, url=画像取得先URL
07-21 15:51:00.448    2178-2238/jp.co.sakaguchi I/art﹕ Alloc sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 74(5KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 63MB/64MB, paused 1.452ms total 15.147ms
07-21 15:51:00.463    2178-2238/jp.co.sakaguchi I/art﹕ Clamp target GC heap from 67MB to 64MB
07-21 15:51:00.465    2178-2238/jp.co.sakaguchi I/art﹕ Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 68(2928B) AllocSpace objects, 1(297KB) LOS objects, 0% free, 63MB/64MB, paused 1.662ms total 11.116ms
07-21 15:51:00.483    2178-2238/jp.co.sakaguchi I/art﹕ Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 11(432B) AllocSpace objects, 1(3MB) LOS objects, 6% free, 59MB/63MB, paused 1.161ms total 12.194ms
07-21 15:51:00.513    2178-2238/jp.co.sakaguchi I/art﹕ Alloc sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 0(0B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 63MB/63MB, paused 1.429ms total 7.145ms
07-21 15:51:00.539    2178-2238/jp.co.sakaguchi I/art﹕ Clamp target GC heap from 67MB to 64MB
07-21 15:51:00.539    2178-2238/jp.co.sakaguchi I/art﹕ Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 10(336B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 63MB/64MB, paused 1.755ms total 18.936ms
07-21 15:51:00.550    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi E/Event﹕ Could not dispatch event: class jp.co.sakaguchi.model.UserEvent to subscribing class class jp.co.sakaguchi.MainActivity
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
            at jp.co.sakaguchi.MainActivity.onEventAlert(MainActivity.java:212)
            at jp.co.sakaguchi.MainActivity.onEvent(MainActivity.java:123)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at de.greenrobot.event.EventBus.invokeSubscriber(EventBus.java:498)
            at de.greenrobot.event.EventBus.postToSubscription(EventBus.java:429)
            at de.greenrobot.event.EventBus.postSingleEventForEventType(EventBus.java:410)
            at de.greenrobot.event.EventBus.postSingleEvent(EventBus.java:383)
            at de.greenrobot.event.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:263)
            at jp.co.sakaguchi.model.AppController.onErrorResponse(AppController.java:134)
            at jp.co.sakaguchi.view.PhotoView$1.onErrorResponse(PhotoView.java:65)
            at com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader$4.run(ImageLoader.java:476)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
07-21 15:51:00.551    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi D/Event﹕ No subscribers registered for event class de.greenrobot.event.SubscriberExceptionEvent
07-21 15:51:00.574    2178-2238/jp.co.sakaguchi I/art﹕ Clamp target GC heap from 67MB to 64MB
07-21 15:51:00.574    2178-2238/jp.co.sakaguchi I/art﹕ Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 335(35KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 63MB/64MB, paused 1.732ms total 31.029ms
07-21 15:51:00.579    2178-2238/jp.co.sakaguchi I/art﹕ Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 1708KB allocation
07-21 15:51:00.621    2178-2238/jp.co.sakaguchi I/art﹕ Clamp target GC heap from 67MB to 64MB
07-21 15:51:00.621    2178-2238/jp.co.sakaguchi I/art﹕ Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 75(3KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 63MB/64MB, paused 2.898ms total 40.899ms
07-21 15:51:00.626    2178-2238/jp.co.sakaguchi E/art﹕ Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 1749612 byte allocation with 627616 free bytes and 612KB until OOM"
07-21 15:51:00.642    2178-2238/jp.co.sakaguchi I/art﹕ Alloc sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 5(368B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 63MB/64MB, paused 1.190ms total 8.460ms
07-21 15:51:00.675    2178-2238/jp.co.sakaguchi I/art﹕ Clamp target GC heap from 67MB to 64MB
07-21 15:51:00.675    2178-2238/jp.co.sakaguchi I/art﹕ Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 27(1504B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 63MB/64MB, paused 3.525ms total 29.061ms
07-21 15:51:00.731    2178-2238/jp.co.sakaguchi I/art﹕ Clamp target GC heap from 67MB to 64MB
07-21 15:51:00.735    2178-2238/jp.co.sakaguchi I/art﹕ Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 7(352B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 63MB/64MB, paused 2.951ms total 36.983ms
07-21 15:51:00.745    2178-2238/jp.co.sakaguchi I/art﹕ Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 1708KB allocation
07-21 15:51:00.783    2178-2238/jp.co.sakaguchi I/art﹕ Clamp target GC heap from 67MB to 64MB
07-21 15:51:00.783    2178-2238/jp.co.sakaguchi I/art﹕ Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 10(352B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 63MB/64MB, paused 3.985ms total 29.294ms
07-21 15:51:00.785    2178-2238/jp.co.sakaguchi E/art﹕ Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 1749612 byte allocation with 628496 free bytes and 613KB until OOM"
07-21 15:51:00.793    2178-2238/jp.co.sakaguchi E/Volley﹕ [161] ImageRequest.parseNetworkResponse: Caught OOM for 304176 byte image, url=画像取得先URL
07-21 15:51:00.918    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi E/Event﹕ Could not dispatch event: class jp.co.sakaguchi.model.UserEvent to subscribing class class jp.co.sakaguchi.MainActivity
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
            at jp.co.sakaguchi.MainActivity.onEventAlert(MainActivity.java:212)
            at jp.co.sakaguchi.MainActivity.onEvent(MainActivity.java:123)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at de.greenrobot.event.EventBus.invokeSubscriber(EventBus.java:498)
            at de.greenrobot.event.EventBus.postToSubscription(EventBus.java:429)
            at de.greenrobot.event.EventBus.postSingleEventForEventType(EventBus.java:410)
            at de.greenrobot.event.EventBus.postSingleEvent(EventBus.java:383)
            at de.greenrobot.event.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:263)
            at jp.co.sakaguchi.model.AppController.onErrorResponse(AppController.java:134)
            at jp.co.sakaguchi.view.PhotoView$1.onErrorResponse(PhotoView.java:65)
            at com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader$4.run(ImageLoader.java:476)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
07-21 15:51:00.918    2178-2178/jp.co.sakaguchi D/Event﹕ No subscribers registered for event class de.greenrobot.event.SubscriberExceptionEvent
```

---

追記
ListViewはページによりますが最高で1ページに50枚の写真があります。
そこで、1ページ目を1枚目から順に表示させて反対に50枚目から順に表示させるというのを試してみました。
すると、折り返し2枚分はhitしたようです。
`LruCache[maxSize=8192,hits=2,misses=50,hitRate=3%]`
これは2枚だけキャッシュに存在したということでしょうか？
また、使用量の差がImageLoaderで取得したBitmapのサイズを違うように見えるのですが、
その分はImageViewなどのサイズ分ということになるのでしょうか？

以下のログはその時の一部抜粋です。

```
07-22 11:48:55.546    3316-3316/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ maxMemory:65536
07-22 11:48:55.546    3316-3316/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ totalMemory:29048
07-22 11:48:55.546    3316-3316/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ freeMemory:1988
07-22 11:48:55.546    3316-3316/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ useMemory:27061
07-22 11:48:55.963    3316-3316/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ size:1708
07-22 11:48:59.496    3316-3316/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ LruCache[maxSize=8192,hits=0,misses=50,hitRate=0%]
07-22 11:48:59.496    3316-3316/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ maxMemory:65536
07-22 11:48:59.496    3316-3316/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ totalMemory:28711
07-22 11:48:59.496    3316-3316/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ freeMemory:1988
07-22 11:48:59.496    3316-3316/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ useMemory:26724
07-22 11:48:59.499    3316-3316/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ size:1708
07-22 11:49:01.793    3316-3316/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ LruCache[maxSize=8192,hits=1,misses=50,hitRate=1%]
07-22 11:49:01.793    3316-3316/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ maxMemory:65536
07-22 11:49:01.793    3316-3316/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ totalMemory:28476
07-22 11:49:01.793    3316-3316/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ freeMemory:4091
07-22 11:49:01.793    3316-3316/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ useMemory:24385
07-22 11:49:01.800    3316-3316/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ size:1708
07-22 11:49:03.896    3316-3316/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ LruCache[maxSize=8192,hits=2,misses=50,hitRate=3%]
07-22 11:49:03.896    3316-3316/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ maxMemory:65536
07-22 11:49:03.896    3316-3316/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ totalMemory:28476
07-22 11:49:03.896    3316-3316/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ freeMemory:1984
07-22 11:49:03.896    3316-3316/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ useMemory:26492
07-22 11:49:04.305    3316-3316/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ size:1708
07-22 11:49:06.383    3316-3316/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ LruCache[maxSize=8192,hits=2,misses=51,hitRate=3%]
07-22 11:49:06.383    3316-3316/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ maxMemory:65536
07-22 11:49:06.383    3316-3316/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ totalMemory:25336
07-22 11:49:06.384    3316-3316/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ freeMemory:1988
07-22 11:49:06.384    3316-3316/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ useMemory:23348
07-22 11:49:06.490    3316-3328/jp.co.sakaguchi I/art﹕ Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 187(7KB) AllocSpace objects, 2(1983KB) LOS objects, 13% free, 24MB/28MB, paused 14.302ms total 55.078ms
07-22 11:49:06.676    3316-3316/jp.co.sakaguchi I/System.out﹕ size:1708
```

また、キャッシュ容量に入る入らないは別として一切キャッシュしないというのを試してみたいのですが、putBitmapでは何もしない、getBitmapではnullを返す、といったことをすれば良いのでしょうか？
その状況で試してもmissesなどが増えないこと以外は状況が変わりませんでした。

---

追記2

```
@Override
protected void entryRemoved(boolean evicted, String key,
                            Bitmap oldValue, Bitmap newValue) {
    if (!oldValue.isRecycled()) {
        oldValue.recycle();
        oldValue = null;
    }
}
```

このように古いBitmapの開放処理を書いたところ、
9ページ目の1枚目ではなく16ページ目の1枚目を表示しようとするまでメモリ不足になりませんでした。
メモリ開放は手動で行わなければならないのですね。

> > これは2枚だけキャッシュに存在したということでしょうか？
>
> そうなります。

やっとLruCache#toStringした時の項目が理解できました。
ありがとうございます。

> RuntimeのメソッドでDalvikヒープの状態を知ることができます

私にはその方法がよくわかりませんでした。
試しにApplication用クラスのonCreateで`Runtime.getRuntime().traceMethodCalls(true);`と書いてみると`java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException`が発生しました。
どうすれば知ることができるのでしょうか？
アプリはAndroid4.4以降対応で、普段はAndroid Studio付属(?)のエミュレータのNexus5(API 22)を使用しています。

大量の写真のキャッシュにメモリキャッシュはあまり有効じゃないとのことでディスクキャッシュを試そうと思ったのですが、その方法がよくわかりません。
ImageLoaderでディスクキャッシュを使用しようと思ったらどのようにすれば良いのでしょうか？

---

追記3
ディスクキャッシュについてはVolleyですでに行われているようですが、デフォルトが5MBらしいので10MB・100MB・1GBに変更して試したものの、どれも改善は見られませんでした。

ヒープダンプを見たところ、やはりbyte[]が一番メモリを消費していることがわかりました。
他にはListView用のAdapterクラスがページの数だけメモリに残っていることなどもわかりました。
[image: Biggest Top-Level Dominator Classes (Overview)]
Adapterクラスがページの数だけ残っているのはページをBackStackに追加しているからでしょうか？

今はいっそVolleyをやめて他を使うなりライブラリ自体を使わないことも検討しています。

Comment: 言葉が悪くてすみません、`Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()`で知ることのできるメモリはDalvikヒープの状態です。3.0より前のAndroidでは画像の確保にNativeヒープという別のメモリ領域を利用している…というのが説明したかった内容です。4.4以降のみ対応のアプリであれば、このことは意識する必要はないと思います。

Comment: 私が勘違いしていたようですみません。
`詳細な状況（実際にメモリに存在する画像など）`を知るのに`Runtimeのメソッド`を使えばできるのかと思っていたのですが、改めて読んだところそのためには`ヒープダンプ`を利用しなければならないのですね。
Android Device Monitorからヒープダンプを取得して Eclipse Memory Analyzerで解析してみようと思います、

Answer (score 4, accepted):

キャッシュの実装の問題ではないように思います。

> LruCache[maxSize=8192,hits=0,misses=12,hitRate=0%]

maxのキャッシュサイズが約8MBなのに対し、画像は1枚辺り約5MBほどあります。

画像2枚でキャッシュの意味がなくなりますので、hitRate=0%となっている通り、キャッシュとして機能していません。`View`から強参照されている`Bitmap`は保持されますので、`LruCache`の容量を常に上回る状態となります。

リストビューなどに多量に表示する画像の場合、`inSampleSize`や`ARGB_4444`などを利用して1枚辺りの画像サイズを抑えてデコードする工夫が必要になるかと思います。

---

**追記**

> これは2枚だけキャッシュに存在したということでしょうか？

そうなります。

`LRUCache`のLRUとは、`Least Recently Used`というアルゴリズムに由来しており、「直近で使われたものをキャッシュ」します。ですので、折り返しは必ずヒットします。`LruCache`の実装は単純なので、ソースコードを読んで見ると理解が深まるかもしれません。

また、`Runtime`のメソッドでDalvikヒープの状態を知ることができますが、ヒープダンプでより詳細な状況（実際にメモリに存在する画像など）を知ることができます。ただし、Android2.X系だと`Bitmap`はNativeヒープに確保されるため、ほぼブラックボックスという点には注意です。